# Apply replacement table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way in MySQL to replace several different strings (like in a table) in one column of an SQL query?

I have a column with entries like "AD", "SP", ... and I want to make a query that gives me all those entries, but replaces AD with "admin" and SP with "support" and so on. So I want to apply the replace function multiple times, but I don't know how to do that.

I tried putting it behind each other like so:

`select replace(PROJNR, 'AD', 'ADMIN.') as PROJ, replace(PROJNR, 'SP', 'SUP.') as PROJ`

But this gave me a single column for each replacement. Can I do that in another way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select (case PROJNR
            when 'AD' then 'ADMIN.'
            when 'SP' then 'SUP.'
            else PROJNR
        end) as PROJ
```